# Url rewriting mod_rewrite with and without query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to rewrite from  domain.com/page/soft-15/android-26/ to page.php?cat=15&os=26 with this code:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)$ page.php?cat=$1&os=$2
```

I thinks it works fine but, how can i rewrite domain.com/page/ and domain.com/page (without the last forward slash) to domain.com/page.php keeping both rules working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok think i got it mixing Jimp & Jon code

```
RewriteRule ^page/?$ page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*-)?([0-9]+)/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*-)?([0-9]+)/?$ page.php?cat=$1&os=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*-)?([0-9]+)/?$ page.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

This math with

```
domain.com/page
domain.com/page/
domain.com/page/soft-15
domain.com/page/soft-15/
domain.com/page/15
domain.com/page/15/
domain.com/page/soft-15/android-26
domain.com/page/soft-15/android-26/
domain.com/page/soft-15/26
domain.com/page/15/26
and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a trailing `/?` to your pattern (before the `$` anchor). The `?` makes the `/` optional.

Additionally, your patterns seem backward, matching the digits before the characters. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(?:([a-zA-Z\d-]*)-)?(\d+)/(?:([a-zA-Z\d-]*)-)?(\d+)/?$ page.php?cat=$1&os=$2
```

That should match these variations like these:

```
domain.com/page/soft-15/android-26
domain.com/page/soft-15/android-26/
domain.com/page/15/android-26
domain.com/page/15/android-26/
domain.com/page/soft-15/26
domain.com/page/soft-15/26/
domain.com/page/15/26
domain.com/page/15/26/
```

Comment: with my code (with or without your trailing ) trying to type domain.com/page/ (or domain.com/page ) just print the requested URL was not found on this server

Comment: I didn't look at your pattern closely before because you said it is working fine, but I don't think that is possible. Your [match characters]-[match digits] patterns are swapped up. I'll take another crack at it.

Comment: as #Jon Lin said, my/your code rewrites to  page.php?cat=soft&os=15

Comment: yes, finally i got what i want, the code is just below my own question

Answer (score 0):

Your backreferences don't seem to jive with the example that you're using:

- `/page/soft-15/android-26/`
- to `page.php?cat=15&os=26`

Your regex looks like it's matching:

- `/page/15-soft/26-android/`

And rewriting to:

- `page.php?cat=15&os=soft`

If you're going by your example, you'd want something like:

```
RewriteRule ^page/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*?-([0-9]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*?-([0-9]+)/?$ page.php?cat=$1&os=$2
RewriteRule ^page/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*?-([0-9]+)/?$ page.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^page/?$ page.php
```

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake with the code, your code works fine but anyway what i was looking for is to work in all condition, with 2 query , **page/soft-15/android-26**, with 1 query , **page/soft-15** or with no query string at all, **page/**

Comment: @Colas Then you need a rule for each one. See the edited answer